# Sharing ASP.Net Application cache in MVC and WCF applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, caching

I have 2 projects, one is an ASP.Net MVC application and the other is a WCF app.

These 2 applications share a common business logic layer, which utilizes the ASP.Net Application cache to store some data for quick retrieval.

I really don't want both apps to maintain the same set of data, but I'm wondering where, exactly, does the ASP.Net caching live?  If I were to share the same app pool, could both processes access that cache?

If not, is there any way to get 2 applications to share the cache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***new solution  use Windows Server AppFabric Caching***

```
https://github.com/geersch/AppFabric

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/caching-wcf-services-part-2

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/AAP314
```

**There were issues in .NET 1.0 and 1.1 but apparently not in 2.0 and upwards** see
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917411